# Aptana Ctrl + Left/Right

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I just started using the Aptana 3 plugin for Eclipse Indigo. When I use the Aptana editor in some contexts it changes the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>. So say I'm editing some JavaScript

```
function foo() {
    alert('bar');
}
```

If the cursor is left of the 'f' in function, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> does nothing, rather than going to the begging of the line, then end of previous line, etc. as it does normally in eclipse. If the cursor is right of the 'o' in foo, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> does nothing, rather than jumping to the curly brace.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to move around often and this is incredibly annoying. I'm not finding any settings relevant to key bindings in the options. Does anyone know how to change this behavior?

**Update: I just tried Aptana on Windows and do not have this issue, it appears to only happen on Linux. I submitted a bug report to Aptana.**

Comment: I don't think it's Aptana - it happens to me in all perspectives / editors.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in Eclipse 3.7: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350362. There are no known workarounds to date, except for to downgrade to Eclipse 3.6.